# angular 2 refactor custom validation logic in service

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have a password FormControl with several custom validators (below just one):

```
password = new FormControl('',
    [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8),
    this.passwordHasLowerCaseValidator.bind(this)]);

passwordHasLowerCaseValidator(control: FormControl) {
    return (...);
}
```

and I want something call the custom validators from a service in order to refactor my signup component like

```
constructor(private customValidators:CustomValidators){}

password = new FormControl('',
    [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8),
    this.customValidators.passwordHasLowerCaseValidator.bind(this)]);
```

I've tried this and It threw errors, I guess the form either couldn't access them or couldn't pass the data to it..

Thanks!

Comment: Just post some more code please. Is your service `@Injectable()` ?

Comment: "threw errors" is all but helpful. Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your validator to return a validator function like

```
passwordHasLowerCaseValidator(customValidators: CustomValidators) {
  return (control: FormControl) => {
    return (...);
    // here you can access "customValidators"
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
constructor(private customValidators:CustomValidators){}

password = new FormControl('',
    [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8),
    this.customValidators.passwordHasLowerCaseValidator(customValidators).bind(this)]);
```

you should get the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks Günther your code works great, only it should be 
passwordHasLowerCaseValidator(customValidators: FormControl){...}
and the call is 
this.customValidators.passwordHasLowerCaseValidator(this.password).bind(this)

Comment: I don't think so. The function is called like `this.customValidators.passwordHasLowerCaseValidator(customValidators)` where `customValidators` is of type `CustomValidators`. The returned function that is actually passed as validator has the parameter `control: FormControl` required by validators. I might have misinterpreted something from your question though but if it works as desired, I assume my assumptions were correct ;-)

Comment: where is CustomValidators located? I should point out that I'm using RC4 (current angular version in ionic 2 beta11)
the code in my previous comment works fine though...not sure if it'll be testable...

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `CustomValidators` is passed as a dependency to the contstructor you added in your question. I don't know more about it.